# CSS3 animation direction not working

Tags: html, css, animation

I have an extending line animation on my site using CSS3. It was created using key frames on the width of the div and naturally it seems to be expanding left to right. However i wish for it to expand from right to left. I have tried using 'reverse' in animation-direction but with no joy. Any ideas why? thanks.

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/edrtB/

CSS

```
.line_left {
    height: 6px;
    width: 32vw;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-animation: expand 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            animation: expand 2s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes expand
{
    from {width: 0vw;}
    to {width: 32vw;}
}

 /* Standard syntax */
@keyframes expand
{
    from {width: 0vw;}
    to {width: 32vw;}
}
```

UPDATE
It has been made clear, that it is hard to see what im trying to achieve. Here is an image of the site logo, and the lines need to animate from the centre outwards.

[image: Explanation]

Comment: You mean like http://jsfiddle.net/edrtB/2/ ?

Comment: yes thats right, did you just float it right? is there another way of achieving this effect?, as floating it right will mess up the layout of my actual site, if that makes sense? thanks for your help

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the entire layout of your site, or at least the relevant parts

Comment: i have edited the post with an image with what im trying to achieve if that helps. thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the animation, it's with how the element is positioned on the page; since it's `float:left`, it's going to stay as far to the left as possible. If you change it to `float:right`, it'll move as far right as possible and expand to the left.

[Here's an updated version of your fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/edrtB/1/)

If you don't want your expanding bar on the right side of the page, you could wrap it in a containing `<div>` and position that however you'd like. See this [new fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/edrtB/3/), in which I'm centering the expanding bar by setting the container's width and giving it `margin:0 auto`.

**Edit**: If you want the fully-expanded bar to be effectively "left-floated," use the above technique of wrapping it in a `<div>`, setting that `div`'s width, and floating it left, as in this [new fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/edrtB/4/).

Comment: right, that makes sense. The reason its float left is down to the design of the page it is included in. There is actually 2 lines with one on the left and one on the right. Is there any way it can float left and expand right?

Comment: If you want it to be touching the left side of the page when fully expanded, create a containing `<div>` and give it `width:32vw; float:left;`--that should do the trick. **Edit** [Another fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/edrtB/4/)

Comment: i have added an image to the post to make it easier to understand what im trying to achieve. thanks for your help

Comment: I believe my previous comment and edited answer solve your problem. Let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: sorry i did not see your comment, that worked great. Thank you for your help!!